# Basic idea of generators of a group

Tags: group-theory

Started studying group theory and I couldn't understand the following:
Given group $G = \langle a,b \rangle$ with binary operation marked $*$ where $a,b$ are the generators of $G$ I understand that $a,a*a,a*b,b*a\in G$
but does it mean that also $a*b*a\in G$?
I think that it's true.

Comment: Yes, it is the minimal group which contains both $a$ and $b$. If $G$ is a group and $a,b\in G$ then $ab\in G$ and $aba\in G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does; it means all finite products of $a$, $b$, and their inverses, all with respect to $*$, are in $G$ (and, in fact, there are no other elements in $G$).